# Entity Framework relationship based on identical key

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm trying to figure out whether its possible to represent a less common model in entity framework. The database I'm using has Persons, PersonFile, Files, Images, and Executables. A Person can have many PersonFiles, each PersonFile has one File, and a File is either an Image or Executable (all of these have their own table, but Images/Executable share their primary key with File, instead of having an explicit foreign key relationship)

My Persons looks like this:

```
public class Person {

  // Properties
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  [JsonProperty("id")]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<PersonFile> PersonFile { get; set; }

}

public class Person_Config : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person> {
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> entity) {
    entity.ToTable("person");

    // Properties
    entity.Property(e => e.Id)
      .HasColumnName("id");

  }
}
```

My PersonUploads looks like this:

```
public class PersonFile {

  // Ids
  public Guid FileId { get; set; }
  public Guid PersonId { get; set; }


  // Relations
  public virtual File File { get; set; }
  public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class PersonFile_Config : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PersonFile> {
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PersonFile> entity) {
    entity.ToTable("_Person_File");

    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.FileId, e.PersonId });

    entity.Property(e => e.FileId)
      .HasColumnName("File_id");

    entity.Property(e => e.PersonId)
      .HasColumnName("Person_id");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.File)
      .WithMany(p => p.PersonFile)
      .HasForeignKey(d => d.FileId)
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Person)
      .WithMany(p => p.PersonFile)
      .HasForeignKey(d => d.PersonId)
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
  }
}
```

My File model looks like this:

```
public class File {
  // Properties
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }

  // Relations
  public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
  public virtual Executable Executable { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<PersonFile> PersonFile { get; set; }
}

public class File_Config : IEntityTypeConfiguration<File> {
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<File> entity) {
    entity.ToTable("File");

    // Properties
    entity.Property(e => e.Id)
      .HasColumnName("id")
      .IsRequired();

    entity.Property(e => e.Type)
      .HasColumnName("type")
      .HasMaxLength(255)
      .IsRequired();

  }
}
```

And for the sake of brevity, my Image and Executables look almost identical, its just the relationship of each of them to file that matters. Here is what Image looks like:

```
public class Image {
  // Properties
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  // Relations
  public virtual File File { get; set; }
}

public class Image_Config : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Image> {
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Image> entity) {
    entity.ToTable("Image");

    entity.Property(e => e.Id)
      .HasColumnName("id")
      .IsRequired();

    entity.HasOne(u => u.File)
      .WithOne(r => r.Image)
      .HasForeignKey<File>(u => u.Id)
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
  }
}
```

While querying with linq, I can retrieve a File by Person no problem by doing something like this:

```
ICollection<File> files_image = await (from file in db.File
                                      join image in db.Image
                                      on file.Id equals image.Id
                                      join personfile in db.PersonUpload
                                      on file.Id equals personfile.UploadId
                                      where personfile.PersonId == id
                                      select file)
                                    .ToListAsync();
```

However, as soon as I try to query specifically for an image using the join, and select that image as the resulting type like so:

```
ICollection<Image> files_image = await (from file in db.File
                                                  join image in db.Image
                                                  on file.Id equals image.Id
                                                  join personfile in db.PersonFile
                                                  on file.Id equals personfile.FileId
                                                  where personfile.PersonId == id
                                                  select image).ToListAsync();
```

I get the following error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'r.PersonId' in 'field list'
```

Does anyone know either where I'm going wrong or how to properly model this kind of relationship? (I think that's the issue, but maybe I'm completely missing something else) Thanks for your help!

Comment: You've defined the navigation properties, you should use them instead of joins to reduce repetition.